# Trigger event on shift+enter key press vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a vue 2.6.x to create a chat-like textbox, where the user can write and then if he press enter the message is sended, know i want to be able to make a line break when the keys `shift+enter` are pressed

this is my `text field`

```
<v-text-field
  @click="answer"
  v-model="text"
  append-icon="send"
  :append-icon-cb="sendMessage"
  label="Write your message..."
  @keyup.native.enter="sendMessage()"
  :multi-line="true"
  :auto-grow="true"
  :rows="1"
  :hide-details="true"
  flat
  solo>
  <v-icon slot="append-icon">send</v-icon>
</v-text-field>
```

how can i listen the event when only the `shift + enter` keys are pressed toggether?

Answer (score 21):

This is how I do it using [exact Modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#exact-Modifier) and `prevent`.

```html
<template>
  <v-textarea
    v-model="text"
    placeholder="Write a message..."
    outlined
    single-line
    dense
    hide-details
    rows="1"
    auto-grow
    @keydown.enter.exact.prevent="sendMessage"
    @keydown.enter.shift.exact.prevent="text += '\n'"
  >
  </v-textarea>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const text = ref('');
    const sendMessage = () => {
      if (!text.value) return;
      // your send message logic
    };

    return {
      text,
      sendMessage,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

`@keydown.enter.exact.prevent` runs the `sendMessage` method when `enter` is pressed without entering a new line

`@keydown.enter.shift.exact.prevent` adds a new line when `shift + enter` is pressed.

Comment: and add ```@keydown.exact="anotherHandlerFunction"```, if you also want to  add a handler that deals with all the other keys without modifiers (ctrl, alt etc...).
Best answer so far for me.

Comment: How would handle 'auto-grow' to grow "up" instead of "down"?

Answer (score 6):

```
<v-textarea auto-grow id="message-area"
placeholder="Write message"
    rows="1"
    solo 
    flat
    v-model="message"
    hide-details
    @keyup.enter="sendMessage"
 >
</v-textarea> 

mounted() {
    sendMessage: function (event) {
        if (event.shiftKey===true && event.key === "Enter") {
           console.log("New line added, message not sended")
           return;
       }
       console.log("Message sended")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Alexey. Please consider explaining your answer. A code only answer doesn't usually help others understand your solution.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24142895w).

Answer (score 1):

```
mounted() {
  let self = this;
  window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.isShiftKeyDown() && event.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log("pressed");
      }
      event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Here on key press the event is fired

- and then there is condition if shift key is pressed along with keyCode = '13' (for enter key)
- you can write your custom function in place of console.log("pressed")

Comment: What about removing the event listener on unmount? Also, [`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). I don't think circumventing Vue makes sense for this relatively simple case.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `@keydown.enter.shift.exact="onSave"` on v-textarea worked. Caveat would be to validate user input inside `onSave` method, since listening on keydown is not connected to vuetify validation/rules logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use exact modifiers also with @click event.

```
//For just left click:
@click.left.exact="clicked"

//For Shift left click:
@click.shift.left.exact="selectClick"
```